# How to control floating-point formatting in Perl using sprintf?

Tags: perl, printf

I usually use `%g`, but it seems [the number of exponent digits is system-dependent](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sprintf.html), and I can't variants like `%.4g` or `%.2g` to work (they simply produce the same results, don't they?).

What I actually would like to do is to use simple floating point representation "when possible" if the number (in absolute value) is in some range (e.g. 10^5 > |x| > 10^-5), otherwise use scientific notation. I also want to limit the number of digits displayed to, say, 5 (so I won't get super huge floating point numbers like 0.12345678901234567890...).

Some examples:

`0.123456890` -> `0.12346`

`0.000000000123456` -> `1.23456e-10`

Can I do that directly in `sprintf` or do I have to write a special wrapper?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you'd have to write a custom wrapper to get the behavior you describe:  As [perlfunc](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sprintf.html) says:

> For "g" and "G", [the precision] specifies the
>   maximum number of digits to show,
>   including those prior to the decimal
>   point and those after it;

Note that leading zeros in the simple floating point representation are *not* counted as "digits".

There are some modules on CPAN that'll help you write a sprintf-like function.  [String::Sprintf](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?String%3a%3aSprintf) is for adding a custom format or two to the regular `sprintf` formats.  [String::Formatter](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?String%3a%3aFormatter) is for starting from scratch with a function that looks like `sprintf` but doesn't inherit any formats from it.